# How to stop scroll animation without affecting the callback (jQuery.animate())

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

In my website app, I use scroll animations by calling this function:

```
function Scroll_To_Top(element, offset, duration, easing, callback = null, args = null) {
    $('html, body').on('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function() { $('html, body').stop(); });
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top - offset}, duration, easing, function() {
        $('html, body').off('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove');

        if (callback != null && args != null) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
        }
        else {
            if (callback != null && args == null) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The animation is stopped as soon as the user scrolls the page and this is what is expected, but this of course also stops the callback passed to the animate function.

Would it be possible to implement something like this without affecting the callback passed to the animate function ?
Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
function Scroll_To_Top(element, offset, duration, easing, callback = null, args = null) {
    $('html, body').on('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function() {
        $('html, body').off('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove');
        $('html, body').stop();

        if ((callback != null) && (args != null)) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
        }
        else {
            if ((callback != null) && (args == null)) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top - offset}, duration, easing, function() {
        $('html, body').off('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove');

        if ((callback != null) && (args != null)) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
        }
        else {
            if ((callback != null) && (args == null)) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```